# How to get Macro PopUp error message in Python

Tags: python, win32com

I am using win32com.client to run the macro from python.This is my requirement

1. I am having multiple macro's first i need to run a macro to test connection
2. If connection is successful then other macros will be executed, if there is any error in connection then Error PopUp will be shown.

I need to capture that error title and click ok button on the macro.

Comment: Not sure if its possible, but you could anticipate an Exception and, when triggered, output a custom error popup (from tkinter for example) and then do stuff based on user input? Hard to say without any code.